# Is there a way to keep SVN historical changes if I want to merge two branches that are not 'ancestrally related'?

Tags: svn, merge, history

I made the terrible mistake and I created a copy (not a branch) of the trunk and I have many commits made on it. I want to integrate my work in trunk and I am struggling to find a way to keep also the the history when I merge them.

Answer (score 0):

A branch in Subversion is nothing but a copy. So if you used `svn cp path/to/trunk path/to/branch` to create the branch, you did everything right and can safely reintegrate your branch (including the history) to trunk once you're finished with your changes.

Comment: I did the copy with Tortoise SVN : right click on trunk -> copy. When I tried to merge I received the warning that they "must be ancestrally related". If I choose to ignore the ancestry, the history of my work on the copy is lost.

Comment: Uh, sorry. I am not familiar with Tortoise, so I cannot comment on its behavior.